# Targeting the same :after pseudo element with 2 classes on the same element

Tags: css

Say I have two classes on a div, .class1 and .class2. If I declare a pseudo element with :after on both .class1 and .class2, and I in effect targeting the same pseudo element with each?

Are there any cross browser issues with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle that shows that whatever the last class is, takes precedence. So I can only assume that the after is based on the element itself and not the class necessarily. If you need more than one, you'll need to use a :before - or add more elements.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/r5dZH/)

### HTML

```
<div class="thing other-thing and-other-thing"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.thing:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    content: "1";
}

.other-thing:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 1em;
    content: "2";
}

.and-other-thing:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 2em;
    content: "3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The :after selector is supported in all **major** browsers, it is not supported in IE7 or below.

For :after to work in IE8, a  must be declared.

Here is a [pretty chart](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/).